# Make functions for operations in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to make a function like this.

```
function getDataFromCollection(collectionName) {
    let data;

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.collection(collectionName).find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            data = result;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });

    return data;
}
```

The problem is that data is undefined, but when I execute console.log(result), it works. Any idea to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not to use `return result` or `res.json(result)` (if you are use express)?

Comment: where I should write return result

Comment: instead of `data = result` and `console.log(result)`

Comment: but if you need to assign result to `data` variable try to do so: https://pastebin.com/dawHhxJR

Comment: that will work but in this way I don't need function and I must copy paste this piece of code everywhere

Comment: I tried, but it still not working

Comment: it returns undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very simple explanation. The `function(err, result)` is essentially asynchronous and is not called immediately but after some time when the data is fetched from mongo. The `function(err, result)` is thus a callback. So, `data` is not set to result immediately but after a while. Now, you return data immediately and don't wait for it to be populated (inside the `function(err, result)` callback) so `undefined` is obviously returned.

The solution would be to use JavaScript's `Promises` which lets you use asynchronous code and callbacks. We return a `Promise` from `getDataFromCollection` and chain a `.then` when we call it. The function or callback that is passed to the `then` is executed when the promise is resolved inside the `getDataFromCollection`function with the data that was passed to the `resolve` function. Thus, the callback inside `then` would be called when you receive the `result`.

All the code -

```
function getDataFromCollection(collectionName) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                  return; 
                }
                db.collection(collectionName).find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                       reject(err);
                       return;
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                    db.close();
                    resolve(result);
               });
           });
        });
    }
```

Consume the function like so.

```
getDataFromCollection("collection")
   .then(function(result) {
      // use result
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err);
   });
```

Read up about `Promises` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).